# GitHub App & Heroku — fatal: Reference has invalid format: 'refs/remotes/heroku/master'

Tags: git, heroku, github-for-mac

I am using the Git app and every time I open a certain repo I get this error:

http://cl.ly/image/271p2h283j1g

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty sure this error is Dropbox related. The conflicted file is due to some kind of Dropbox reconciliation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're certainly using Dropbox to sync your project among multiple computers. While performing the sync, the tool detected a conflict between two files and created a backup with the suffix `(COMPUTER_NAME's conflicted copy DATE)`.

Unfortunately, the conflicted file is a reference, and according to Git naming convention, the name of a reference cannot contain spaces. See **[git check-ref-format man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ref-format.html)** for more information about rules describing how references should be named.

As references are only text files containing pointers to a commit Sha or another reference, fixing this is not a complex issue.

**In order to resolve this, the following steps should be followed:**

- Within your project directory, open both the `.git/refs/remotes/heroku/master` and the `.git/refs/remotes/heroku/master (Richard Burton's conflicted copy 2012-11-24)` files in a text editor and decide which content is the most up to date (ie. which is the real tip of the remote master branch on Heroku).
- Copy the correct SHA and paste it in the file named `.git/refs/remotes/heroku/master`
- Drop the `.git/refs/remotes/heroku/master (Richard Burton's conflicted copy 2012-11-24)` file.

**Note:** you may have other files in conflict. In order to be thorough, launch a recursive search in your project for files which name contains `conflicted copy`

**Note 2:**  `git ls-remote --heads heroku` may be handy in this situation as it will request the remote repository about its known branchs.

Comment: Thanks! How can I find this file and change it? Spotlight is letting me down.

Comment: Within your project usually lives the `.git` folder. It is hidden. `ls  -a` should list it.

Comment: Was this answer helpful to you?

Comment: Yes! I went `cd .git`, `open .` and found all the stuff in there.

Comment: nulltoken: Absolute answer thank you very much. So better to avoid drop box for synch folders in multiple computers rite?